# session timeout multiple tabs in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I used the bootstrap session timeout modal in my AngularJS application but this function just working in one tab and when I work on multiple tabs my old tabs logout even that I am active in another tabs.

```
$.sessionTimeout({
    keepAliveUrl: '#/',
    logoutUrl: '/account/login',
    redirUrl: '/account/logout',
    warnAfter: 5000,
    redirAfter: 10000,
    countdownMessage: 'Redirecting in {timer} seconds.'
});
```

and
bootstrap-session-timeout.js
I used these 2 codes in my angular js layout